# Adding login account

Tags: support, login, openid

My Stack Overflow account is integrated to my university account which is now blocked because I have graduated. I want to add a new email id to my current account because I can't login to new devices anymore. I use Firefox to visit Stack Overflow, but Firefox shows me an error:

> Stack Overflow needs to access JavaScript from another domain. Which is not found or failed to load.

I can't post questions, etc. and can't add a new email address because some buttons here trigger JavaScript, so buttons don't work. I can't change my browser because then logging in would be a problem because my email is blocked. I'm posting the question from the Android app. What should I do?

Comment: Anyone plz reply?

Comment: You can request new credentials be added to your account [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to right direction...

Comment: @Laurel: that would be a good answer to write up.